# Bulk update of aggregates based on state change of an aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm working on an event sourced application following DDD and CQRS principles, which allows the posting of ads to sell goods.

There's one specific invariant that i'm trying to model which would seem to involve a bulk update of AR's, and I don't really know how to go about it.

The invariant is as such:

- A Member can post an ad
- A Member could be banned by an Admin
- If a Member is banned, his ads must be suspended

for the purposes of the discussion, an Ad needs to have a status, as a Member can buy an item by clicking on an ad, so it's important to know if an ad is active.

I have designed my aggregate roots as such:

- Member
- Ad
- Order

A Member can be a buyer or a seller, depending on the context, so I decorate the member object as needed.

When ads are published, they are of course inserted in a read model.

Now, when a Member is banned, there's an event associated that the Member AR triggers.
MemberWasBanned (MemberId)

My question is how do I go about finding every Ad that the member owns, and suspend them?

While I could rely on the member status for a buy transaction, it's important that the Ad tracks its status as there are other similar operations that could trigger the sending of an email for instance to the member indicating that his ads were suspended for such or such reason.

So my best approach after a lot of thinking is to create a long running process, in which I create a handler for MemberWasBanned, then go look for his active ads in the read model, and issue commands to suspend them one by one.

Am I missing something? I thought of using a process manager, but read that you shouldn't access the read side from a PM. In any case a PM in most cases determines the command sent to ONE AR.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "I thought of using a process manager, but read that you shouldn't access the read side from a PM" - you don't do it only for resilience reasons; otherwise the PM needs to build a private state based on the Events, just like a Read-model

Comment: "In any case a PM in most cases determines the command sent to ONE AR." - No, the PM could send commands to many ARs

Comment: Constantin, thanks for the comments - re. 1 and building state into the PM, it's one thing I still struggle with understanding. Would there be one instance of PM in that case per Ad? and them how would the state be restored in case you decide to replay all events? Seems that there would be some sort of repository needed to rebuild it? and re. 2- Would in that case accessing a read model (through a service) from my PM to read the list of Ads belonging to a user, then issue a Suspend command against them be a valid design?

Comment: re. 2: if you sacrifice the independence of the PM but reduce code duplication. It's you choice

Comment: re.1: an instance of PM per User seems more appropriate; in general you do not replay all events on a PM unless you have a state that  is used to ignore the already-processed events

Comment: My PMs are decorated by a persistence that ignores the already-processed-events transparently. My PMs are simply Read-models that are  decorated with this *layer*

Comment: Ha, yes meant one instance per user, thanks for the correction. About decorating the read model with a PM layer sort of, that's a great design. thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: One last question: "if you sacrifice the independence of the PM but reduce code duplication". I'm not sure what the alternative (the one that would involve code duplication) is and that's what I'm struggling with - I need to get the IDs of the ads that belong to a user somewhere - Would I (as suggested by Pedro below) keep a list and get them from the AR itself? that doesn't feel right in that it would be a query op on an AR, but hard to draw the line...

Comment: in CQRS you are not allowed to query the Aggregate. The alternative is that the PM builds an internal list of needed IDs by subscribing to the relevant events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172706/discussion-between-konel-sum-and-constantin-galbenu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a messaging mechanism, maybe you can "explode" the *MemberWasBanned* event.

Publish the *MemberWasBanned* (or equivalent) event through your messaging pipeline, and subscribe to it from the context that handles ads. When this event is received in your messaging mechanism, you can explode it into multiple *DisableAd* events that will also be sent through your messaging system, each of them targetting one current ad of the banned member.

Each of these events, then, will only write on a single Aggregate (each ad, disabling it) when they're processed by the messaging mechanism.

Concurrently, the banned user will prevent further ads from being inserted, so you will be safe on that end as well.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, it's a good approach, the problem remains however that while I know the member ID, I can't get the ad IDs as when a member posts an ad, I record the member ID in the ad aggregate, but I don't keep a list of ads in the member aggregate (doing so would require using a process manager to avoid updating 2 aggregates in the same transaction). Therefore I would have to query the read model, which is what I was trying to avoid doing

Comment: why are you avoiding so much reading through the read model? maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, eventual consistency... I guess, being somewhat of a newcomer to the subject, most of my research (here for instance http://cqrs.nu/Faq) indicates that you should avoid accessing the read model from the write side, (command handler or process manager). I guess sometimes that rule can be broken, and I'm looking for validation if this is one of those times... the obvious place would be to do it in a process manager, through a service I guess.

Comment: Eventual consistency is an issue. but you can evaluate that on multiple levels: if your read model generation is attached to your messaging mechanism and your messaging mechanism guarantees order of delivery, the MemberWasBanned explosion will happen after any pending new Ads are created, thus, not suffering from eventual consistency issues... On the other hand, if you can't guarantee that, you can shield yourself to catch stragglers through some sort cleanup process (either through events or not). But you're absolutely right that something will need to be done regarding eventual consistency.

Comment: Or you can just decide the hassle of handling this consistency scenario is too big and keep the list of ads within the member and go with the process manager to write to both aggregates on creation...

Comment: Thanlks! the order of execution is a good point, although it does tie the model to the implementation, but it's manageable. It's been helpful to discuss this, thanks!